# Let f(x)= $\lfloor x \rfloor+ \lfloor -x \rfloor$ Prove: The limit $\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x)$ exists for every $x_0\in R$.

Tags: calculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Let $f:R \to R$ be $f(x)=\lfloor x \rfloor+ \lfloor -x \rfloor$ (floor function)
>
> Prove or disprove: The limit $\lim_{x \to x_0}f(x)$ exists for every $x_0\in R$ and define what types of point discontinuities the function has, if any.

1.) if the limit exists we need to prove that both one-sided limits exist and are equal to each other.

$\lim_{x\to x_0^+}\lfloor x \rfloor+ \lfloor -x \rfloor$ = $\lfloor x_0^+ \rfloor+ \lfloor -x_0^+ \rfloor$= $x_0 - x_0 =0$

Similarly:

$\lim_{x\to {x_0-}}f(x)=0$

But this seems to only works for $x_0\gt0$

Picking $x_0=-4.3$ we get that f(x)=$\lfloor -4.3 \rfloor+ \lfloor 4.3 \rfloor=-5+4=-1$

Checking the one sided limits, we get that indeed for $x_0\lt 0$ exist and are equal to each other.

Does this make sense?

And for Discontinuities, it makes sense for them to be at 0 since picking something a little bit smaller than zero will give us -2, picking something a little bigger will give us 0. Therefore the discontinuity will be that the one-sided limits are not equal to each other (not sure of name.)

Would appreciate a quick look over to see if I'm right.

Comment: write $x_0 = n + \epsilon$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z}, \epsilon \in [0,1)$, and consider the case $\epsilon > 0$ and $\epsilon = 0$

Comment: Where did you get $\lfloor x_0^+ \rfloor+ \lfloor -x_0^+ \rfloor=x_0-x_0$? This is just not true. For any non integer the value is $-1$ and for any integer the value is $0$. There are infinitely many points without a limit.

Comment: @ElliotG ah thank you! So the limit doesn't exist since the one-sided limits are not equal to each other?

Comment: Actually the limits equal one another but there is a third requirement that the function actually take on that value (which it doesn't). Hope that helps

Comment: Ah a jump discontinuity, since we'll get 0 for integers, while the one sided limits will be -1 correct?

Comment: @ElliotG to me $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x)$ means the left and right sided limit, without caring of $f(x_0)$

Comment: I have never seen any definition that wasn't equivalent to the delta-epsilon formation, in which case you need $f(x_0)$ to equal the left and right limits.

Answer (score 3):

Simplify the expression of $f$:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 0&\text{if } x\in\mathbf Z\\
-1 &\text{otherwise }\end{cases},$$
hence the limit is $-1$ at every point.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x_0\in\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Z}$ we have  $$\lim_{x\to x_0^+}\lfloor x \rfloor=\lim_{x\to x_0^-}\lfloor x \rfloor=\lim_{x\to x_0}\lfloor x \rfloor=\lfloor x_0 \rfloor$$
so 
$$
\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=\lim_{x\to x_0}\lfloor x \rfloor+\lfloor -x \rfloor=\lfloor x_0 \rfloor+\lfloor -x_0 \rfloor=\lfloor x_0 \rfloor-\lfloor x_0 \rfloor-1=-1
$$
Let now $x_0\in \mathbb{Z}$, then :
$$
\lim_{x\to x_0^+}\lfloor x \rfloor=x_0\;; \; \lim_{x\to x_0^-}\lfloor x \rfloor=x_0-1
$$
then 
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{x\to x_0^+}f(x)&=&\lim_{x\to x_0^+}(\lfloor x \rfloor +\lfloor -x\rfloor)\\
&=&\lim_{x\to x_0^+}\lfloor x \rfloor +\lim_{x\to x_0^+}\lfloor -x\rfloor\\ 
&=&\lim_{x\to x_0^+}\lfloor x \rfloor +\lim_{\begin{array}{}x\to x_0\\ x>x_0 \end{array}}\lfloor -x\rfloor\\
&=&\lim_{x\to x_0^+}\lfloor x \rfloor +\lim_{\begin{array}{}-x\to -x_0\\ -x<-x_0 \end{array}}\lfloor -x\rfloor\\
&=&\lfloor x_0 \rfloor+\lim_{-x\to -x_0^-}\lfloor -x \rfloor\\
&=&\lfloor x_0 \rfloor+\lfloor -x_0 \rfloor-1\\
&=&\lfloor x_0 \rfloor-\lfloor x_0 \rfloor-1\\
&=& -1\\
\end{eqnarray}
and
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{x\to x_0^-}f(x)&=&\lim_{x\to x_0^-}(\lfloor x \rfloor +\lfloor -x\rfloor)\\
&=&\lim_{x\to x_0^-}\lfloor x \rfloor +\lim_{x\to x_0^-}\lfloor -x\rfloor\\ 
&=&\lim_{x\to x_0^-}\lfloor x \rfloor +\lim_{\begin{array}{}x\to x_0\\ x<x_0 \end{array}}\lfloor -x\rfloor\\
&=&\lim_{x\to x_0^-}\lfloor x \rfloor +\lim_{\begin{array}{}-x\to -x_0\\ -x>-x_0 \end{array}}\lfloor -x\rfloor\\
&=&\lfloor x_0 \rfloor-1+\lim_{-x\to -x_0^+}\lfloor -x \rfloor\\
&=&\lfloor x_0 \rfloor-1+\lfloor -x_0 \rfloor\\
&=&\lfloor x_0 \rfloor-1-\lfloor x_0 \rfloor\\
&=& -1\\
\end{eqnarray}
so 
$$
\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=-1 ; \forall x_0\in\mathbb{R} 
$$
But in $\mathbb{Z}$ 
$$
f(x)=\lfloor x \rfloor+\lfloor -x \rfloor=\lfloor x \rfloor-\lfloor x \rfloor=0
$$
so the set $\mathbb{Z}$  is a set of removable discontinuity points of $f$.